# Most creative/diabolical/entertaining way to find Python version?

Tags: popularity-contest, python

There are important differences between Python 2 and 3, so it's often useful to know which version of the interpreter is running your code. The straightforward method is something like this:

```
def get_python_version():
    import sys
    return sys.version_info.major
```

But you can exploit other differences to come up with other solutions to this. My favorite so far is this:

```
def get_python_version():
    version = 3;[2 for version in range(3)]
    return version
```

What's the most creative/diabolical/entertaining snippet you can come up with that returns the Python version?

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55963/42963

Comment: Related: [link1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25913/valid-through-the-ages), [link2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48898/produce-different-behaviour-in-all-versions-of-your-language)